# rsyslog configuration based on port

Tags: configuration, rsyslog

I need some help configuring my `rsyslog` service. I was wondering if it was possible to configure remote logging based on incoming ports. For example:

If the logs are coming from `172.28.132.43` then put the logs in the `/var/log/enviromux/` directory.
If the logs are coming from `172.28.132.43:9191` put the logs in the `/var/log/sierra/` directory. (port 9191)

This is my configuration so far, but there are some errors on line 4 &5. Can anyone tell me what I do wrong:

```
1 $template remote-sierras,"/var/log/sierra/%FROMHOST%/%programname%.log"
2 $template remote-enviromux, "/var/log/enviromux/%FROMHOST%.log"
3 if($fromhost=="ZABBIX") then stop
4 if($fromhost=="*:9191") then *.* ?remote-sierras & stop
5 *.* ?remote-enviromux & stop
```

My version off `rsyslog`is 8.32.0 and I run it on Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html) seems to suggest that the `fromhost` property does not include the source port number.

What you could try instead is use one of the other properties to filter these messages. For instance you could try something like `if($programname == "sierras")...`, `if ($msg contains "sierras")`, or something similar.